# Android: Fatal Exceptions in GoogleAuthUtil

Tags: android, fatal-error

I am working on an Android app which uses Google for authentication. Our code for fetching a token to verify a user's identity is as follows, following the "auth" sample Android project's GetNameInForeground.java:

```
/**
* Get a authentication token if one is not available. If the error is not recoverable then
* it displays the error message on parent activity right away.
*/
@Override
protected String fetchToken() throws IOException {
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException playEx) {
        // GooglePlayServices.apk is either old, disabled, or not present.
        mActivity.showErrorDialog(playEx.getConnectionStatusCode());
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
        // Unable to authenticate, but the user can fix this.
        // Forward the user to the appropriate activity.
      onError("Authorization problem with Google account", userRecoverableException);
        //mActivity.startActivityForResult(userRecoverableException.getIntent(), mRequestCode);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
        onError("Unrecoverable error " + fatalException.getMessage(), fatalException);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When logging in, we regularly receive the error "Unrecoverable error unknown." This suggests that we are getting fatalExceptions from calling GoogleAuthUtil.getToken, but we can't tell why. http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html doesn't give much information regarding error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this error when I accidentally tested a binary that was signed with the Temporary Eclipse Generated credentials. I believe you need to sign the binaries with the same keys used to generate the server client-id in [Google Play Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) . If using Eclipse, do a signed export of the app and install.

Comment: Since when did the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method start throwing a GoogleAuthException with message "BadUsername" for an email that is not registered on a device, instead of the previous exception IllegalArgumentException with message "Non existing account 'email_address'" ?  
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context , java.lang.String, java.lang.String)